# Finding the only multiple zero of a quadratic function

Tags: roots, quadratics

I don't know how to figure this problem out. Can someone please help?

For what value of $\;b\;$ will $\;f(x)=x^2 + bx + 400\;$ have $\;-20\;$ as its only zero?

Comment: For $x=-20$ the condition $f(x)=0$ is fulfilled if $b=0$. Do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, I do! Thank you!

Comment: @callculus When $x=-20, b=0$, we have $x^2+400=800$.

Comment: If a quadratic has $-20$ as it only root then it is $c(x+20)^2$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: @saulspatz Ouch! Yes, you´re right. Sorry.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use descriptive titles. "Can someone help me figure this out?" is completely useless.

Answer (score 2):

The number $\;-20\;$ is a zero of the function $\;f(x)=x^2+bx+400\;$ if and only if $\;f(-20)=0\;.$

$(-20)^2+b(-20)+400=0\;,$

$400-20b+400=0\;,$

$-20b=-800\;,$

$20b=800\;,$

$b=\dfrac{800}{20}=40\;.$

Moreover, if $\;b=40\;,\;$ then it results that $\;f(x)=x^2+40x+400=(x+20)^2\;,$

consequently,

$f(x)=(x+20)^2=0\iff x+20=0\iff x=-20\;,$

so $\;-20\;$ is the only zero of $\;f(x)\;.$

Hence, the value of $\;b\;$ such that $\;f(x)=x^2+bx+400\;$ has $\;-20\;$ as its only zero, is

$b=40\;.$

**Another way to solve the exercise:**

$f(x)=x^2+bx+400\;.$

$x^2+bx+400=0\;,$

and, by applying the quadratic formula’s determinant,

$\Delta=b^2-4ac=b^2-4\cdot1\cdot400=b^2-1600\;.$

$f(x)=x^2+bx+400\;$ has only a zero if and only if $\;\Delta=0\;.$

$b^2-1600=0\;,$

$b^2=1600\;,$

$b=\pm\sqrt{1600}=\pm40\;.$

If $\;b=-40\;,\;x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}=\dfrac{40\pm0}{2}=20\;.$

If $\;b=40\;,\;x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}=\dfrac{-40\pm0}{2}=-20\;.$

Hence, the value of $\;b\;$ such that $\;f(x)=x^2+bx+400\;$ has $\;-20\;$ as its only zero, is

$b=40\;.$

Comment: This is absolutely the solution, but I think I have to mention the quadratic formula's determinant.

Comment: Now, is it ok ?

Comment: Yes, it was OK already (I gave it a +1), I thought I just needed to mention that, because to solve questions alike one needs to know it (I mean I refer to the OP).

Answer (score 0):

For a quadratic equation having one root, its discriminant is zero, i.e.

$$b^2- 4\cdot 400=0$$

which leads to $b=\pm40$. Check to determine that $b=40$ from the given root $-20$.